# ¿Es verdad que la palabra 'alrededor' tiene origen árabe?

Tags: etimología

¿Tiene la palabra 'alrededor' (o 'al rededor') origen árabe? ¿Sabéis otras palabras con el mismo origen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alrededor proviene de `al + rededor` (contorno). En esto coinciden la RAE y el diccionario de María Moliner. Por tanto no, no tiene origen árabe.

Sí es cierto que muchas otras palabras de castellano que empiezan por `al-` sí tienen procedencia árabe. Por ejemplo: alfombra, alcalde, alcoba, alcohol, alfiler, alforja...

Y otras parabras que no empiezan por "al" pero también con origen árabe serían: aceite, barrio, cenefa...

Puedes encontrar un listado en esta página de la Junta de Andalucía: http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/averroes/ies_boabdil/departamentos/vocab-arabe.htm

Answer (score 4):

Alrededor es la comunión de "al" + "derredor" así que dudo que su origen sea árabe.

Comment: Definición de [derredor](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=derredor&origen=REDRAE): *Circuito o contorno de una cosa.*